# BaseAdapter + ViewHolder not working

Tags: android

Hey guys I have a viewholder + a base adapter but it isnt working

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    // get the selected entry
    AI entry = (AI) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {           
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        holder.position = position;
        holder.title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        holder.iconimg = entry.icon;

        new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

        v.setTag(holder);   
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(entry.title);

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

The the items in the list dont show anything what am I doing wrong?

EDIT Here is the whole class

```
public class AIAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<?> mListAppInfo;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AIAdapter(Context c, List<?> list, PackageManager pm) {
        mContext = c;
        mListAppInfo = list;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        // get the selected entry
        AI entry = (AI) mListAppInfo.get(position);

        // inflate new layout if null
        if(v == null) {           
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

            holder.position = position;
            holder.title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            holder.iconimg = entry.icon;

            new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
            .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

            v.setTag(holder);   
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(entry.title);

        // return view
        return v;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask{
        private int mPosition;
        private ViewHolder mHolder;
        private Rect mOldBounds = new Rect();

        public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
            mPosition = position;
            mHolder = holder;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            Drawable icon = mHolder.iconimg;

            int width = 64;
            int height = 64;

            final int iconWidth = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final int iconHeight = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (icon instanceof PaintDrawable) {
                PaintDrawable painter = (PaintDrawable) icon;
                painter.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
                painter.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
            }

            if (width > 0 && height > 0 && (width < iconWidth || height < iconHeight)) {
                final float ratio = (float) iconWidth / iconHeight;

                if (iconWidth > iconHeight) {
                    height = (int) (width / ratio);
                } else if (iconHeight > iconWidth) {
                    width = (int) (height * ratio);
                }

                final Bitmap.Config c =
                        icon.getOpacity() != PixelFormat.OPAQUE ?
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                final Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, c);
                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(thumb);
                canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(Paint.DITHER_FLAG, 0));
                mOldBounds.set(icon.getBounds());
                icon.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                icon.draw(canvas);
                icon.setBounds(mOldBounds);
                icon = new BitmapDrawable(thumb);
            }

            return icon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable bitmap) {
            if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
                mHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
            }
        }

    }
}

class ViewHolder{
    public int position;
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView icon;
    public Drawable iconimg;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. All the entry.title and entry.icon have data. Though nothing is showing on the listview. The layout list does have an imageview and textview. This works without the viewholder but once i add the viewholder it doesnt

Comment: Check a few things, 1. That you have items in your datasource, 2. That it's entering your getView(), 3. Try setting a color to your textview

Comment: Does `entry.title` return anything? What does your debugger show you?

Comment: Also, not related, but if each row has a different icon, then your Thumbnail task should come outside your if-else block

Comment: added a code I tried logging the entry variables and they did show data and even if I et the color to textview its the same. Just an idea of what it looks like http://i49.tinypic.com/34s5tuq.png

Answer (score 2):

For one thing it's not necessary to create  "v" object, you can use convertView directly. 
Did you correctly override your BaseAdapter class? For instance the getCount() method...does it return mListAppInfo.size()?

At a first glance your method should work; Could you maybe copy/paste your entire class?

Answer (score 1):

When applying the viewHolder pattern, your ViewHolder class needs to be static;

A bit offtopic now, you should be careful with those asynctasks that you issue quite a lot, you may want to consider using a thread pool.
Likewise, try to consider SparseArray or HashMap instead of your list of items in your adapter, they're faster in retrieving an item at a given index then the List.

Try setting a brakepoint at this line: " holder.title.setText(entry.title);" Does it get there? Is all the information correct?